# Getting a GAE datastore single entity, which is more efficient

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datastore

Which is more CPU efficient, 1, 2 or 3?

```
key = something.key()
id = something.key().id()
```

1) `db.GqlQuery("select.....").fetch(1)[0]`

2) `db.get(key)`

3) `get_by_id(id)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option 1 is less efficient, because it requires a query. Incidentally, note that if you want exactly one result, you can call `get()` on the Query, which will return the first result, or None if there are none.

2 and 3 are identical; `get_by_id` is just syntactic sugar for constructing a key and fetching it with `get`.